SUMIF is giving me wacky numbers when inside array. Other answered questions were for more complicated issues. How can I fix this?
Link to Spreadsheet
"=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(C4:C,C4:C,'Gear Input'!BM5:BM)),COUNTA(C4:C),1)"
I'm basically taking unique values from a raw set of data in 'Gear Input!'BJ5:BJ, dumping them in 'Gear Sorter!'C4:C then trying to add up the numbers in 'Gear Input!'BM5:BM.
The basic answer is to copy/paste a SUMIF in every cell, but this is sloppy and I won't be the only one using this so I really need an array formula to work... But when I use SUMIF inside an array formula, it seems to break.
Thanks to taking a peak.
I was expecting SUMIF to work within the Array Formula, but it seems to act differently. The other answers I found that related to this issue all seemed to try an answer different questions.


You may try:
=map(C4:index(C:C,match(,0/(C:C<>""))),lambda(Σ,sumif('Gear Input'!BJ:BJ,Σ,'Gear Input'!BM:BM)))



Wow, a perfect answer right out of the gate. I have to admit that I never would have figured this out. MAP and LAMBDA are new to me. Lots to think about. Thank you.
